# Missing parameter while creating/updating objects related to uploading images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

EDIT: Narrowed the error down to when I attempt to upload an image via paperclip

Alright so just tried to add/edit elements of my database which is up on heroku and started getting errors. Checked the heroku logs got this

```
2012-08-23T19:10:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 363ms
2012-08-23T19:10:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-23T19:10:42+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2012-08-23T19:10:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/apartments_controller.rb:68:in `new'
2012-08-23T19:10:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/apartments_controller.rb:68:in `create'
```

If i check whats on line 68 of the apt controller i get this...

```
def create
@apartment = Apartment.new(params[:apartment])
```

Not really sure why this started causing errors its been working great all up until a bit ago if anyone might be able to help out itd be appreciated.

New View:

```
<div id="new"><center><h1>New apartment</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<br />
<%= link_to 'Back', apartments_path %></center>
</div>
```

_form View:

```
<div id="formApt">
<%= form_for @apartment, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @apartment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@apartment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this apartment from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% @apartment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :agent %><br />
   <%= f.collection_select :agent, Apartment::AGENTS, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true %><br />
         </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :location %><br />
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :availability %><br />
     <%= f.collection_select :availability, Apartment::AVAILSEL, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Bed %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :Bed %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Bath %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :Bath %><br />
   </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Rent %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Rent %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Pets %><br />
     <%= f.collection_select :Pets, Apartment::PETSSEL, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true %><br />
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Security_Deposit %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :Security_Deposit %><br />
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Parking %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Parking %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Laundry %><br />
      <%= f.collection_select :Laundy, Apartment::LAUNDRYSEL, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true %><br />
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Owner %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Owner %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Date_Avail %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :Date_Avail %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Type_Heat %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :Type_Heat, Apartment::HEATSEL, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :AC %><br />
     <%= f.collection_select :AC, Apartment::ACSEL, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true %><br />
  </div><br />  
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :photo %><br />
     <%= f.file_field :photo2 %><br />
     <%= f.file_field :photo3 %><br />
      <%= f.file_field :photo4 %><br />
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Description %><br />
    <%= text_area "apartment", "description", "cols" => 60, "rows" => 10 %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
  <% f.fields_for :apartment_image do |apartment| %>
  <% if apartment.object.new_record? %>
  <p>
  <%= apartment.label :caption, "Image Caption" %>
  <%= apartment.text_field :caption %>
  </p>
  <p>
 <% end %>
  </p> 
   </div>
   <% end %><% end %>
</div>
```

Show View

```
<head>
<!-- First, add jQuery (and jQuery UI if using custom easing or animation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.timers-1.2" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.easing.1.3" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.galleryview-3.0-dev" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.galleryview-3.0-dev", :media => "all" %>
<!-- Lastly, call the galleryView() function on your unordered list(s) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myGallery').galleryView({
    transition_speed: 2000,         //INT - duration of panel/frame transition (in milliseconds)
    transition_interval: 4000,      //INT - delay between panel/frame transitions (in milliseconds)
    easing: 'swing',                //STRING - easing method to use for animations (jQuery provides 'swing' or 'linear', more available with jQuery UI or Easing plugin)
    show_panels: true,              //BOOLEAN - flag to show or hide panel portion of gallery
    show_panel_nav: false,          //BOOLEAN - flag to show or hide panel navigation buttons
    enable_overlays: true,          //BOOLEAN - flag to show or hide panel overlays

    panel_width: 900,               //INT - width of gallery panel (in pixels)
    panel_height: 500,              //INT - height of gallery panel (in pixels)
    panel_animation: 'slide',       //STRING - animation method for panel transitions (crossfade,fade,slide,none)
    panel_scale: 'crop',            //STRING - cropping option for panel images (crop = scale image and fit to aspect ratio determined by panel_width and panel_height, fit = scale image and preserve original aspect ratio)
    overlay_position: 'bottom',     //STRING - position of panel overlay (bottom, top)
    pan_images: true,               //BOOLEAN - flag to allow user to grab/drag oversized images within gallery
    pan_style: 'drag',              //STRING - panning method (drag = user clicks and drags image to pan, track = image automatically pans based on mouse position
    pan_smoothness: 15,             //INT - determines smoothness of tracking pan animation (higher number = smoother)
    start_frame: 1,                 //INT - index of panel/frame to show first when gallery loads
    show_filmstrip: true,           //BOOLEAN - flag to show or hide filmstrip portion of gallery
    show_filmstrip_nav: true,       //BOOLEAN - flag indicating whether to display navigation buttons
    enable_slideshow: false,            //BOOLEAN - flag indicating whether to display slideshow play/pause button
    autoplay: false,                //BOOLEAN - flag to start slideshow on gallery load
    show_captions: true,            //BOOLEAN - flag to show or hide frame captions 
    filmstrip_size: 3,              //INT - number of frames to show in filmstrip-only gallery
    filmstrip_style: 'scroll',      //STRING - type of filmstrip to use (scroll = display one line of frames, scroll filmstrip if necessary, showall = display multiple rows of frames if necessary)
    filmstrip_position: 'bottom',   //STRING - position of filmstrip within gallery (bottom, top, left, right)
    frame_width: 164,               //INT - width of filmstrip frames (in pixels)
    frame_height: 80,               //INT - width of filmstrip frames (in pixels)
    frame_opacity: 0.5,             //FLOAT - transparency of non-active frames (1.0 = opaque, 0.0 = transparent)
    frame_scale: 'crop',            //STRING - cropping option for filmstrip images (same as above)
    frame_gap: 5,                   //INT - spacing between frames within filmstrip (in pixels)
    show_infobar: true,             //BOOLEAN - flag to show or hide infobar
    infobar_opacity: 1              //FLOAT - transparency for info bar
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body { 
        margin: 2em; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="new"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br />
    <ul id="myGallery">
        <li> <%= image_tag @apartment.photo.url (:large) %>
        <li> <%= image_tag @apartment.photo2.url (:large) %>
        <li> <%= image_tag @apartment.photo3.url (:large) %>
        <li> <%= image_tag @apartment.photo4.url (:large) %>
</ul>   
    <p>
  <b>Agent:</b>
   <%= @apartment.agent %>
</p>
 <p>
  <b>Location:</b>
  <%= @apartment.location %>
</p>
 <p>
  <b>Availability:</b>
  <%= @apartment.availability %>
</p>
 <p>
  <b>Bed:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Bed %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Bath:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Bath %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Rent:</b>
  $<%= @apartment.Rent %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Pets:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Pets %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Security deposit:</b>
  $<%= @apartment.Security_Deposit %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Parking:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Parking %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Laundy:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Laundy %>
 </p>
 <p>
  <b>Owner:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Owner %>
 </p>
  <p>
  <b>Date avail:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Date_Avail %>
 </p>
 <p>
  <b>Type heat:</b>
  <%= @apartment.Type_Heat %>
 </p>
<p>
  <b>Ac:</b>
  <%= @apartment.AC %>
 </p>
<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @apartment.description %>
</p>

<center>
<nav2>

<span id="home2"> <%= link_to image_tag("home.png"), root_url %></span>
    <span id="apartments2"><%= link_to image_tag("apartments.png"), {:action =>'aptMenu', :controller => 'apartments'} %></span>
    <a href="http://livewellchicago.herokuapp.com/?cat=forms"> <%= image_tag("forms.png") %>            </a>
   <a href="http://livewellchicago.herokuapp.com/?cat=landlords">
    <%= image_tag("landlords.png")%>    </a>
    <a href="http://livewellchicago.herokuapp.com/?cat=contactUs">
    <%= image_tag("contactus.png") %>    </a>


</nav2>
</div>
</body>
```

Params:

```
{"commit"=>"Create Apartment",
 "apartment"=>{"Laundy"=>"In Building",
 "availability"=>"RENTED",
 "Owner"=>"mike",
 "Date_Avail(1i)"=>"2012",
 "Date_Avail(2i)"=>"8",
 "agent"=>"Jason Gold",
 "Security_Deposit"=>"1200",
 "Date_Avail(3i)"=>"23",
 "Rent"=>"3232",
 "Bed"=>"3232",
 "Type_Heat"=>"Radiator",
 "location"=>"ewew",
 "Bath"=>"32323",
 "Pets"=>"Cats Only",
 "Parking"=>"no",
 "AC"=>"Window Unit",
 "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x103e34c80 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bg/dnbp4t6s12g5bh3_yrj6ntvr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120823-62841-rogrlw-0>,
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apartment[photo]\"; filename=\"livingroom.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @original_filename="livingroom.jpg">,
 "description"=>"description goes here"},
 "authenticity_token"=>"3KhQ0Bh3D+DZSTbPPPhWmgJLqTQ7HyOx45Coa23N4mI=",
 "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

Comment: Btw, the error is indicating that `params[:apartment]` is nil

Comment: Hi prusswan sorry about that the title was taken from my last post accidentally and I forgot to change it, thats my mistake. My issue, however, simply had to do with the params[:apartment] being nil. Im trying to understand how exactly that could wind up being nil out of nowhere even though I havent touched the controller recently and it was working a short while ago. If you might have any ideas behind the cause of it or a solution itd be greatly appreciated, and again sorry for the initial confusion regarding the title

Comment: You still need to post the views that are related to the new/create actions, to see what is not working for the params

Comment: I couldnt think of any other views that related to the new and create actions besides _form, new, and show possibly

Comment: For the params that you posted, do you see the error following immediately after? If so, we need to look at the model `apartment.rb` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so basically this was my own fault. Had to do with the apartment model and the format of an has_attached_file statement

```
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:small => "150x150>", :large => "800x720>", :convert_options => { :all =>     '-auto-orient' }}
```

Essentually the :convert_options portion was causing the param for the image to be nil which prevented anything from being added to the database (unless you avoided adding pictures). But thanks Prusswan for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= text_area "apartment" ... %>
```

should probably be:

```
<%= f.text_area ... %>
```

Edit: The two versions are equivalent actually based on [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for), so problem is somewhere else.

Comment: doing that causes a 'ArgumentError in Apartments#new'              wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)  
Extracted source (around line #87):  

84:   
85:     <div class="field">
86:     <%= f.label :Description %><br />
87:     <%= f.text_area "apartment", "description", "cols" => 60, "rows" => 10 %><br />
88:   </div>
89: 
90:   <div class="actions">

Comment: Sorry for the poor format, not sure how to format code in comments

Comment: can you test this locally and post the params that are currently being sent to the controller? (with or without the proposed change)

Comment: OK with a little trial and error I realized the problem is coming from the images. I can create a new object successfully as long as no pictures are added